# Hot wire anemometry and gas species

Tags: flow, thermal-conductivity, instrument

Hot wire anemometry is a technology that measures mass flow of a gas stream in the neighborhood of a heated wire. The sensitivity of a flow sensor using this technology is usually specified for a specific gas or gas mixture (e.g. Air). Is there a way to correct the sensitivity factor for gas species other than what the sensor was intended to measure?

Comment: What have you tried? Normally anemometers must be calibrated in low-turbulence flows of known velocity to get the calibration coefficients. Is there something that makes you think that won't work for anything other than air?

Comment: It's just a bit more difficult to calibrate when the gas is a mixture of water vapor and dry air. As far as controlling a precise RH. My thinking is more towards a method of correction based on the physics and known physical properties of the gas such as thermal conductivity.

Comment: I guess a better question is what have you searched for -- there's a ton of literature out there for determining calibrations in multicomponent flows. I'm not an experimentalist so I can't provide a more recent example without searching longer, but [here's a paper from 1970](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.5814) for determining both concentration and velocity using hot wires. I bet if you traced citations from that paper forward or backward in time, you'll find the information you need.

Comment: Indeed, most mass flow controller (MFC) makers have tables to convert the readout of an MFC calibrated for one gas to another (or a mixture). An example is MKS, which lists correction factors for a variety of gases relative to N2 at http://www.mksinst.com/docs/UR/MFCGasCorrection.aspx.

Comment: Yes I suppose that may be the only way - the manufacturer ( or otherwise calibrate as @tpg2114 suggested). I just read an article claiming that the relationship between velocity and readout are 'inextricably' combined as a function of up to at least 3 non-dimensional numbers and the specific geometry of the sensor. Looks like assumptions and simplifications will only lead to errors.

Comment: @JonCuster, that is a cool table.  Note that the noble gases are all ~1.5, diatomic things H2, N2, O2 (air) are ~1.0.. and after that it gets weirder.  But you can see it might be a question of how much energy the thing loses when it crashes into the wire.